# Is it safe to change registry names from VBOX to something else in Virtualbox?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, windows-registry

I'm trying to make a stealthy Windows 7 VM on an Ubuntu host but in the registry there are many keys and values which have "VBOX" written (see screenshot attached). Therefore, is it safe if I change the registry key names to something more realistic? Or are there keys and values I shouldn't touch regardless?

Some registry keys with VBOX written on them:
[image: Some registry keys with VBOX written on them]

Comment: Don't change internal VirtualBox entries. What does "stealthy" mean?

Comment: That it doesn't have any (or as little as possible) virtualisation traces (i.e. looks more like a real PC).

Comment: the registery is a configuration repository. applications store values in it, and use those values at runtime. in order to do that the applicaiton must know the name of the value it wants and where it is located in the registery, so those names are more or less hard coded within the application. if you rename them or change their path, the app won't be able to find them.

Comment: If your intention is to misguide malware that is so sophisticated that it could escape  a VM, you should not be using Windows 7, as it is EOL for over 2 1/2 years now.

Comment: Hi mashuptwice, although you are right, I'm required to analyse malware in a Windows 7 VM.

Comment: @mashuptwice, it is common that malware analysis must be performed with older software. you can't analyze its behavior if mitigations against that particular exploit prevents it from "working". i took a practical self-defense via offense course once, and we had problems with half the labs because of how hard it is to get modern software to not update. after a while, google itself stopped accepting traffic from the entire network our lab facility was on. its great in practice, but frustrating if you re trying to learn basic offensive techniques.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to hide the fact that an installation was done in a
VirtualBox VM - there are too many virtualization traces, including
for example the ancient virtualized hardware that today can only be
found in a VirtualBox VM.

It would be easy for any knowledgeable person to detect the traces of
VirtualBox. Changing the device names that you found will not help,
as there are much better methods.

Comment: And is there a guide somewhere online to, at least try and to remove as many traces as possible?

Comment: There isn't, and it's flatly impossible. What might work better is to take a physical computer and to P2V (physical-to-virtual). The resulting VM will then have less traces of VirtualBox.

Comment: It definetely looks as a brilliant way to minimise virtualisation traces. Unfortunately, I have no Windows 7 license do I'm using a trial version for now but it's something worth knowing so thanks a lot for telling me!

Comment: @jefazo92 - There is no such thing as a "trial" of Windows.